# How to change compression of Wordpress uploads including original image

Tags: media-library, compression

We are currently using this to change the compression used on jpgs when uploaded to the WP media library:

```
add_filter(‘jpeg_quality’, function($arg){return 75;});
```

However, this does not compress the original image. We sometimes need to display the original image on our website and this also needs to be compressed. How do we do this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Thumbnail add_image_size PNG not working

Comment: @Litalino I converted this from an answer into a comment, but I couldn't tell if you were replying to the question or towebtours answer? If you have a new question you should click the ask question button, this isn't a messageboard/forum so you shouldn't look for the closest question to your problem and try to continue discussion

Answer (score 2):

For compressing the uploaded image I wrote a simple code snippet that immediately overwrites a newly uploaded file with an image whose quality can be specified:

```
function wt_handle_upload_callback( $data ) {
    $image_quality = 30; // Change this according to your needs
    $file_path = $data['file'];
    $image = false;

    switch ( $data['type'] ) {
        case 'image/jpeg': {
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg( $file_path );
            imagejpeg( $image, $file_path, $image_quality );
            break;          
        }

        case 'image/png': {
            $image = imagecreatefrompng( $file_path );
            imagepng( $image, $file_path, $image_quality );
            break;          
        }

        case 'image/gif': {         
            // Nothing to do here since imagegif doesn't have an 'image quality' option
            break;
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload', 'wt_handle_upload_callback' );
```

Regarding the additional image sizes (just change the return value):

```
add_filter( 'wp_editor_set_quality', function( $quality ) { return 30; } );
```

Comment: This is great code snippet. BUT, on my tests, this function removes all image EXIF/IPTC data too. Can you please modify it to have option to preserve image EXIF data? than I will use it for sure. Thank you @webtoure

Comment: Thanks! This solution works and should be marked as solution.